# plot and display images as animation (as a video, in the same window)

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I want to display the sequence as a video, it doesn't work

```
for k in range(2,totalFrames+1):
    image_path='img'+str(k)+'.jpg'
    img = cv2.imread(image_path,0)
    cv2.namedWindow('win')
    cv2.imshow('win',img)
```

I can accept a solution with matplotlib too

Comment: You should add `cv2.waitKey(1)` after imshow.

Comment: Currently your program is displaying the image correctly but its immediately being closed. Add `cv2.waitKey()` where the parameter is the duration to keep the window open in ms. Add `0` for the parameter to keep the window up indefinitely until there is a key press